# Products added to Cart vs Products ordered report in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We are trying to implement Google analytics on our e-commerce site ..

In the order confirmation page we added e-commerce tracking code and its tracking all the revenue ..

We have added an event and are tracking items added to cart..

Is there a possible way where we can compare both these and make a report?

Please let me know your ideas..

Thank you in advance

KR

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom report like this one for this purpose:

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=2i8P7u4zQ_uq87xelzeIVQ

You need to customize it of course to suit your needs. It is now just a drilldown of Event Category, Action, Label with Total events, Revenue, conversion rate and transactions. I am not sure what metrics you are after, but it is a start.

Comment: Thank you MrSponge..I got what I am looking for..Will customize and go forward..thank you